# popup window in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am writing a Chrome extension, and I want a login window to be popped up when users click on the context menu so that user can input username and password. In Chrome extension, I only found `chrome.pageAction.setPopup` and `chrome.browserAction.setPopup` can be used to show popup windows,  but they show popups only when the page action's icon or browser action's icon is clicked, not the context menu. Of course, I can use javascript prompt box to do this, but the problem is the password cannot be masked in the prompt box. So I am wondering if there are some other ways to create a popup window in Chrome extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Pick and choose:

- <sup><s>[`showModalDialog(<String url> [, <object arguments>])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog)

  Opens a dialog-like window, in which you can load a page within your chrome extension. HTML can be used.</s></sup>
  Do **not** use showModalDialog, [it is going to be removed from Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345831).
- [`window.open(<String url> [, <String window_name>[, <String windowFeatures>]])`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345831)
  Opens a window, which, unlike the previous method, does not appear as a dialog. The user can minimize the window, and continue with something else.
- [`chrome.windows.create(<object createData [, <function callback>]>)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)
  (Specific to Chrome extensions) Create a new window, with given arguments (size, url, position, ...).

All of these methods allows you (your extension) to open a new window/dialog, and handle the logic from that page. This page should be packaged with your extension.
See [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to pass the entered data to your extension.

### Demo

Tabs within your extension have direct access to the background page using [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage). I'll demonstrate this feature in this demo, as well as a conventional way of message passing:

### `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Dialog tester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["open-dialog.js"]
  }]
}
```

### `background.js`

```
// Handle requests for passwords
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.type === 'request_password') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('dialog.html'),
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
            // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                focused: true
                // incognito, top, left, ...
            });
        });
    }
});
function setPassword(password) {
    // Do something, eg..:
    console.log(password);
};
```

### `open-dialog.js`

```
if (confirm('Open dialog for testing?'))
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'request_password'});
```

### `dialog.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Dialog test</title></head><body>
<form>
    <input id="pass" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<script src="dialog.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

### `dialog.js`

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgWindow) {
        bgWindow.setPassword(password);
        window.close();     // Close dialog
    });
};
```

## Documentation for used methods

- [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<request>, <function callback>)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)`.addListener(<function listener>)`
- [`chrome.extension.getURL(<String path>)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL)
- [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(<function callback>)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage)
- [`chrome.tabs.create(<object createData> [, <function callback>])`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)
- [`chrome.windows.create(<object createProperties> [, <function callback>])`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)

Comment: Hi, Rob, thanks for your reply. It's very helpful. But I only found how to make message passing between background page and content scripts, so could you tell me how to communicate between the dialog-like window and background page, so that the imputed username and password can be sent back to background page to make a request for a token in OAuth 2.0? Thanks again!

Comment: @RobW - Is there anyway I can stick  the pop window to the current tab where it was initiated. It is a stand alone popup window currently.

Comment: @Vidit Do you mean adding to the tab strip (use `chrome.tabs.create`) or in the current page (don't do that)?

Comment: @RobW In the current page, not in a new tab. I don't want the users to go away from the current page. So like a small popup show may be at the right side of the page or the bottom right or even the top right like browser action popup. I just posted a question, which can give you more detail perhaps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875730/chrome-extension-create-custom-popup-from-context-menu-click

Comment: @RobW, What do you mean by the phrase "tabs within your extension"? Also, is there a way to stop the broadcast nature of "chrome.runtime.sendMessage", sending the request only to the background runtime?

Comment: @Pacerier Tabs in the browser with the URL of a page from your extension, e.g. chrome-extension://extensionid/page.html. You cannot change the broadcast nature of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, but as an alternative you could use [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) to establish a message channel (port) to one of more specific destinations, and use the port's `postMessage` and `onMessage` APIs to communicate.

Comment: Update: In the example code, method "chrome.extension.getURL()" should be renamed to [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL).  This solution is still very helpful 5 years on. +1