# Cannot get the tab ID of the background page in Chrome extension

Tags: dialog, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension, in which there is a dialog-like window to let users input the username and password, which are then sent back to background page to make a request for the token in OAuth 2.0.

To send the username and password from dialog window back to background page, I used the following codes (inside the dialog window .html file):

```
<script>
function usrpwd(){
    var up = {};
    up.usr = document.login_form.usr.value;
    up.pwd = document.login_form.pwd.value;
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(window.dialogArguments,up);
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

where the `window.dialogArguments` is supposed to be the tab ID of the extension's background page.

And the dialog window is opened in background page by

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "show Modal Dialog",
  "contexts" : ["all", "page"], 
  "onclick": handle_click
});

function handle_click(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
        console.log('tab ', tab);   
        window.showModalDialog("login_popup.html", tab.id, "dialogHeight:300px; dialogLeft:200px;");
    });
}
```

The `tab.id` is supposed to be the ID of the background page, and it will be passed to dialog window and assigned to `window.dialogArguments`.

Also in the background page, the username and password are received by,

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request){
        console.log("Username: ", request.usr);
        console.log("Username: ", request.pwd);
    }
);
```

However, `console.log('tab ', tab)` inside the `handle_click` function always shows that the getSelected tab is the tab where the context menu got clicked, not the background page. So I am wondering how to get the tab ID of the background page in this case. Or is there any other better ways to communicate between dialog window and background page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background pages do not have a `tabId`, since they are not tabs.

To send a message to the background page, use [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) (`extension` instead of `tabs`).

PS. [Full demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341102/938089?popup-window-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Hi, Rob, one more question. Now I can send the username and password from the a dialog window (opened by `window.showModalDialog`) back to the background page by using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage`, but I have to input and submit the username and password TWICE to close the dialog window. I don't know what's the problem. The dialog.html is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQkYX/2/). Thank you!

Comment: @chaohuang Press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the console, and check whether something weird happens. Instead of using `window.close()`, you can also use [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest), and use the supplied `sender.tab.id` to close it using [`chrome.tabs.remove`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove).

Comment: I used `chrome.tabs.create` to replace the `window.showModalDialog`, then there is no problem. I guess there are some bugs regarding to `window.showModalDialog` in Chrome. Thanks for your patient help. I appreciate it.