# Is it possible to make a Chrome Extension popup as a movable window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a Chrome Extension that needs the user to enter some information from the webpage that they're on. However, the extension window/popup is sometimes in the way of the information on the webpage.

Is it possible to make the popup into a window that can be dragged around Chrome at all? I've only found solutions online that pertain to Chrome Apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340481/popup-window-in-chrome-extension