# Chrome extension show image from api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that pops up every hour with a image from an api.
The every hour part is done and I can show a alert box, but alert boxes does not support images. So I am wondering if anyone can help me.

What i need is:
How to show a modal with a image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popup window in Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340481/popup-window-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: See also chrome.notifications API.