# Why DOM update on every opening(chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Default position:

[image]

When I checked:

[image]

Then I click anywhere on the page to hide the output of dom extension(not show popup.html);

But when I open extension again it is unchecked(default position):

[image]

**I need that chrome extension not reset to default position every time when I open it.**

Maybe I need to use some property in manifest.json or not?

manifest.json:

```
 {
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "a",
"short_name": "b",
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"description": "a",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "a",
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "abc"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"cookies",
"clipboardWrite",
"storage",
"background",
"<all_urls>",
"tabs"
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is a regular page that is closed when you click outside it. Like for regular pages, any *state* within it is lost when the tab closes.

You should store it when the checkbox changes (via `chrome.storage.local.set()`) and restore it when the popup is opened again (`chrome.storage.local.get()`)

Or use a regular popup so that it doesn't close automatically, if you prefer that behavior.

Comment: Thx, but can you write about regular popup in two words or send some url about it, as I can't find useful info in holy google.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341102/288906