# How to create a Popup window in an extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create a popup window in the extension that I pull through GreasyFork, but since there is only JS there, I can’t bring the window to the output.
How can I create a popup window in js?

I tried to wrap it in a function and substitute it in my own execution conditions, but how to attach the rest? if they are not considered in js?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7ZNo.png)
I also tried that, but it doesn't work either
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrE9L.png)

Comment: This link might help you, the answer has been validated : [Pop-Up window in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10340481/16067048)

Answer (score 1):

İf you want open a new window:

```
chrome.windows.create({
   url: 'popup.html',
   type: 'popup', width: 400, height: 400,
});
```

İf you want open with on new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url:"popup.html" });
```

But you must add "tabs" permission to use this method.

Answer (score -1):

You should handle this in the manifest file. [read this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#user_interface)

Comment: This link does not answer the question. It's like saying: "look it up on the internet."